# linux connect() timeout and syncookies

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

In the man page for connect(2) [version for Linux 2.6.7 2004-06-23], the section describing ETIMEDOUT says:

> ETIMEDOUT Timeout while attempting connection. The server may be too
>   busy to accept new connections. Note that for IP sockets the timeout
>   may be very long when syncookies are enabled on the server.

The same remark appears at least also in release 3.35 of the Linux man-pages project.

I don't follow how enabling syncookies on the server cause the client to have potentially longer timeouts.

Comment: A syncookie is cryptographically encoded directly in the server's `SYN+ACK` reply to the client's `SYN`. It may take some extra time for the server to verify a syncookie, which would delay processing of the final `ACK` that establishes the connection. Also, the use of syncookies disables the use of TCP options, that might have otherwise enhanced the performance of the connection.  See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies).

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. As I understand it, from the client's perspective a connect() finishes upon receiving the SYN+ACK, so the final ACK in the handshake wouldn't even enter the latency picture on the connecting side.

Comment: Then the only possibility would be if the generation of the syncookie is delaying the `SYN+ACK` from being sent. According to the page I linked you to: "the server is limited to only 8 unique MSS values, as that is all that can be encoded in 3 bits."  Maybe if the server has a lot of connections, or at least a lot of pending connections, it may take longer for a unique MSS to become available for the connection being `SYN+ACK`ed? Or maybe the cryptography takes a long time to create a new hash? That seems like the only candidates.

Comment: My interpretation of that part of the article is that the restriction to 8 unique MSS values doesn't mean that it is a limited resource like a semaphore. It seems to me, it means it has a limited universe of values to choose from, but it can repeat the same MSS.

Answer (score 2):

My only explanation is that this is a bug in the man pages and that is not what the author meant to say.  The source to handle connection timeouts in Linux is relatively simple and can been seen [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c?v=linux-2.6#L127) in the retransmits_timed_out() and tcp_write_timeout() functions.

tcp_retransmit_timer() is called based on the normal exponential backoff timer (i.e. a syn is retransmitted just like any other packet, there is no special handling).  tcp_retransmit_timer() calls tcp_write_timeout() ([line 396](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c?v=linux-2.6#L396)) which, if the socket is in the SYN_SENT or SYN_RECV state, sets a variable retry_until to either icsk_syn_retries (if it has been set using setsockopt()) or the sysctl tcp_syn_retries value.  It also sets syn_set = true.  These two are passed on the retransmits_timed_out(), which checks to see if there have been retry_until attempts to send the syn.  If so it returns true and tcp_write_err() is called, which returns the ETIMEDOUT error ([line 37](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/ipv4/tcp_timer.c?v=linux-2.6#L37)).

In the case that syn_set is true, retransmits_timed_out uses TCP_TIMEOUT_INIT as the base timeout for its calculations, which is a constant (defined [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/include/net/tcp.h?v=linux-2.6#L136)).  So even if the presence of syncookies somehow magically changed the retransmit timer, it couldn't change how retransmits_timed_out() calculates if enough time has passed to warrant returning ETIMEDOUT.  It could only possibly change the number of retransmits, but icsk_syn_retries is only set [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/net/ipv4/tcp.c?v=linux-2.6#L2644) when handling a setsockopt, and sysctl_tcp_syn_retries is only set through the sysctl mechanism.

So I don't see any way that syncookies on the server could have any effect on the connect() timeout.  Which, as you point out, makes sense.  How could the client know that the server was using syncookies?  Especially before even receiving a syn|ack, which would complete connect().

I'm guessing the author was trying to convey that the timeout should be set relatively high, because with the advent of syncookies a server that is totally backlogged can still get around to successfully making a connection, but it might take some time.  (Note that this line dates back to before the current man-pages repo was setup, as it was brought in with the initial import of man-pages 1.70 in 2004).

Answer (score 0):

Syncookies are made to block a syn flood. It takes some time to generate them and validate them. If your client disconnects, I think it may wait the appropriate 64 seconds to generate the new 5 top bits: `t mod 32,` where `t` is a 32-bit time counter that increases every 64 seconds

This is just what I assume: at least it has something to do with validating the server and the client taking up some time.

[Click here for more info](http://cr.yp.to/syncookies.html)